# Nexus 7706 - switchport trunk allowed vlan not working - all VLANs are being allowed

Tags: cisco, vlan, trunk, cisco-nexus, cisco-nx-os

I noticed that my two Nexus 7706 do not limit the trunk VLANs to what `switchport trunk allowed vlan` is set to.

Sample configuration:

```
interface Ethernet1/15
  switchport
  switchport mode trunk
  switchport trunk allowed vlan 201,601-607,712,801-810,990
  no shutdown
```

With the configuration above, I can connect a router on port E1/15, set up VLAN 101 for example, and send/receive traffic, even though VLAN 101 is not explicitly allowed.
Also broadcast traffic from other VLANs that are not being allowed, is being sent down this trunk port.

What do I miss?

Both switches run NX-OS 8.2(1).

Here's the switchport info:

```
# show interface Ethernet 1/15 switch
Name: Ethernet1/15
  Switchport: Enabled
  Switchport Monitor: Not enabled 
  Operational Mode: trunk
  Access Mode VLAN: 1 (default)
  Trunking Native Mode VLAN: 1 (default)
  Trunking VLANs Allowed: 201,601-607,712,801-810,990
  FabricPath Topology List Allowed: 0
  Administrative private-vlan primary host-association: none
  Administrative private-vlan secondary host-association: none
  Administrative private-vlan primary mapping: none
  Administrative private-vlan secondary mapping: none
  Administrative private-vlan trunk native VLAN: none
  Administrative private-vlan trunk encapsulation: dot1q
  Administrative private-vlan trunk normal VLANs: none
  Administrative private-vlan trunk private VLANs: none
  Operational private-vlan: none
```

And: `show spanning-tree vlan 101` output

```
# show spanning-tree vlan 101

MST0000
  Spanning tree enabled protocol mstp
  Root ID    Priority    4096
             Address     00de.fbf0.e941
             This bridge is the root
             Hello Time  2  sec  Max Age 20 sec  Forward Delay 15 sec

  Bridge ID  Priority    4096   (priority 4096 sys-id-ext 0)
             Address     00de.fbf0.e941
             Hello Time  2  sec  Max Age 20 sec  Forward Delay 15 sec

Interface        Role Sts Cost      Prio.Nbr Type
---------------- ---- --- --------- -------- --------------------------------
Po1              Desg FWD 500       128.4096 (vPC peer-link) Network P2p 
Po5              Desg FWD 200       128.4100 (vPC) P2p Bound(PVST) 
Po9              Desg FWD 200       128.4104 (vPC) Edge P2p 
Po10             Desg FWD 200       128.4105 (vPC) Edge P2p 
Po11             Desg FWD 200       128.4106 (vPC) P2p 
Po12             Desg FWD 200       128.4107 (vPC) P2p Bound(PVST) 
Po13             Desg FWD 200       128.4108 (vPC) Edge P2p 
Po18             Desg FWD 200       128.4113 (vPC) Edge P2p 
Po19             Desg FWD 200       128.4114 (vPC) Edge P2p 
Po20             Desg FWD 200       128.4115 (vPC) P2p Bound(PVST) 
Eth1/4           Desg FWD 20000     128.132  P2p Bound(PVST) 
Eth1/5           Desg FWD 20000     128.133  P2p Bound(PVST) 
Eth1/6           Desg FWD 20000     128.134  P2p Bound(PVST) 
Eth1/8           Desg FWD 20000     128.136  P2p Bound(PVST) 
Eth1/10          Desg FWD 20000     128.138  P2p Bound(PVST) 
Eth1/11          Desg FWD 20000     128.139  P2p Bound(PVST)
```

Here's a network topology diagram.
[image]
All switches connect to both Nexus and use LACP with VPC.

**Update:**
I noticed that if I explicitly add vlan 101 to the trunk port allowed vlans
`switchport trunk allowed vlan add 101`
And then I remove it
`switchport trunk allowed vlan remove 101`
Then it stops being sent down the trunk port, as it should.

So it seems that there's some bug or something has gotten our of sync and the trunk ports do not update their configuration properly.

Is there a way to 'refresh' the config on all ports without reloading the whole switch?
Adding and removing all VLANs to all trunk ports, is too much of a hassle to do manually.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the output from `show interface Ethernet 1/15 switch`

Comment: @RonTrunk done :)

Comment: Also `show spanning-tree vlan 110`

Comment: @RonTrunk Added.

Comment: the output doesn't explain what you're seeing.  Can you provide a simple diagram?  There must be other switches in your network.

Comment: I updated the output, I messed up my original post by typing VLAN 110 instead of 101.

Comment: The `show spanning tree vlan 101` doesn't show E1/15. Why do you think that might be?

Comment: Should it show E1/15? Isn't the current output correct according to how E1/15 is configured? What's troublesome is that the actual behavior does not match the current configuration. VLAN 101 is just an example. All VLANs are getting through E1/15

Comment: `show cdp neighbor` will show you if there are other switches connected to other interfaces.

Comment: I know what switches are connected where. I am making a simple topology diagram to help you. I am not sure how that makes any difference though. Shouldn't `switchport trunk allowed vlan` explicitly limit which VLANs can pass through a given trunk port? Right know, all VLANs are accessible through all trunk ports, regardless of which VLANs I am allowing on each trunk port.

Comment: How do you know that? If a VLAN comes into the switch through a different interface, whether trunk or access, it still gets into the switch. How are you determining it is through that one trunk interface?

Comment: It is quite possible that someone connected two switches together on access interfaces configured for VLAN 101, and you will bleed that VLAN in that way. That is why I suggested using the `show cdp neighbor` command. That will show such a situation.

Comment: Even if that were the case (which is not) that would account only for VLAN 101. I am seeing ALL vlans being passed through all trunk ports, regardless of which VLANs I allow to pass through. Everything is connected to the Nexus switches only. No other switch connects to any other switch.

Comment: Run a `show mac address-table vlan 101` - does it show anything on E1/15? If not, your router might not do the things you think you configured.

Comment: For example, you do not allow VLAN 101 on Ethernet 1/15, and it is not coming in through there, but it is coming in through multiple other interfaces. I think you need to paste the full configuration into your question.

Comment: If I assign an IP on VLAN 110 on the router, then it shows the MAC of the router. If not, it doesn't show anything from E1/15 because there's nothing behind E1/15 to show. Again, VLAN 101 is just an example. ALL VLANs exhibit the same behavior. With the current configuration I can add an IP on VLAN 30 on the router and it will work. My question is why `switchport trunk allowed vlan` doesn't do what is supposed to do. I don't allow neither VLAN 110 nor 30 and yet, they work. And this happens on ALL trunk ports. Not just E1/15.

Comment: @RonMaupin I capture the traffic coming from E1/15 to the router and it IS coming from that port. The router is not connected to anywhere else to get that traffic from.

Comment: The router is not connected to the other Nexus?

Comment: No. It's just a test connection to troubleshoot the problem I am describing.

Comment: `switchport trunk allowed vlan x,y-z` is supposed to limit the trunk to the listed VLANs. If it doesn't you should consider contacting TAC for a suspected bug. Have you checked the readmes for later NX-OS releases?